# How to prevent text from flowing outside its parent box in css?

Tags: css, overflow

The text isnt shrinking to fit the div box, it is overflowing instead
Expecting the text to shrink to fit the div box

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 12px;
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Reading List</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean font size must be link with div size?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.parent-box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden; /* or scroll, auto */
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-box">
  <p>This is some text that should not flow outside the box.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Deny wrapping (`white-space: nowrap;`) for `p` tag

Change height for `div`. because `12px` is too little

Add `overflow: hidden;` for `div`

Optional. Change padding and margin

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Reading List</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the `<fit-text>` Web Component, see: https://fit-text.github.io

```html
<script src="https://fit-text.github.io/element.js"></script>

<style>
  fit-text {
    width:25vw;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    border:1px solid blue;
  }
</style>

<fit-text>Hello Cool<br>Web Component<br>World!</fit-text>
```